# What size hub do I need for a Giant Escape 2 (2016)?

Tags: wheels, hybrid-bike, rear-wheel, wheel-building, giant

As I mentioned in a [previous question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46259/rebuild-or-replace-rear-wheel-on-giant-escape-2-2016), I'm in the process of replacing the stock rear wheel on my Giant Escape 2 (2016)(any comments/answers related to why and whether I need to replace it should be entered there). The one thing I can't seem to find in the specs is whether I have a 130mm or 135mm wide wheel/hub/or whatever that measurement pertains to. How do I find out? How do bike shops know? If I measure this myself, what do I actually measure--the rear wheel dropouts or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measurement there is known as "O.L.D." or Over-Locknut Diameter.  It's the width of the opening in the frame between your dropouts, with a hub installed.  So from outside-of-locknut to the opposing side outside-of-locknut on your hub.  This can be measured with calipers or (more difficult but possible) with a ruler.  Remember in this case you need to be very accurate in measuring, since it's either 130 or 135 millimeters, and that 5 millimeter difference is very small(about a quarter inch).  If you're sure about the type of bike you have, this could be an easier way.  130mm hubs are generally only used on true road bikes(700x~20-25c).  135mm is used on Mountain or Hybrid bikes(any 26", 29", 27.5", or 700x~30-50c).  Looking at Giant's website, this should be a Hybrid, and 135mm OLD.

Comment: I see- so I take it you can't just remove the wheel and measure the space between the dropouts because there could be a little flex when the hub is actually installed? Anyway, thanks for the very specific information. I think you're probably right that it is 135, but I'll go ahead and measure as you've suggested just to be sure.

Comment: That is exactly why you can't just measure the space.  On aluminum bikes there usually is minimal if any flex, but it may be enough to get a false positive one way or the other.